# How to access Vue.js component data from a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Based on [vuejs docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) I would expect the following code to work, but `this` is null when I click the button:

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <button v-on:click="test">Test </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  name: 'hello',
    methods: {
        test: () => {
            console.log('log data.message', this.msg); 
        }
    },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the full demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vq3ovx9n70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `test()` method to:

```
test: function() {
        console.log('log data.message', this.msg); 
    }
```

Arrow functions don't bind `this` the way you want here.